# Same filename different path in subtree

Tags: python, file, directory

I need to make symbolik links to files in a directory (dir1). Each file must have a symbolik link, if there is a file with same filename but in subfolder, i need to make a symlink with a suffix. Here is an example:
dir1 contains the files exe1, sh1, bash. The directory paper contains the file bash too, and the files file1, file2 file3.

```
exe1 → dir1/exe1
sh1 → dir1/sh1
bash → dir1/bash
bash1 → dir1/paper/bash
file1 → dir1/paper/file1
file2 → dir1/paper/file2
file3 → dir1/paper/file3
```

The code is python. Anyone could help me?

Comment: What have you tried so far. Any piece of code or something that you have written/tried??

Comment: So I see you would like some free code...

Comment: I don't want free code, i just have no idea about how to check if file is present more times in subfolders, and then add suffix to symlink i need to create.

Comment: what result you want if `dir1/paper/` contain `exe1`? It `exe11`?

Comment: @MichaelKazarian yes, exactly!

Comment: @AntonioFalcone My answer do it :)

Answer (score 0):

Why not just checking if a link already exists before creating a new one, and increment a suffix until getting a new link name?

Answer (score 0):

```
import os, sys

def maker(inputdir, outputdir, suffix=""):
    if not (chechdir(inputdir) and chechdir(outputdir)): sys.exit(0)
    for pos in os.listdir(inputdir):
        name =  os.path.abspath(inputdir+"/"+pos)
        if os.path.isdir(name):
            maker(name, outputdir, suffix+"1")
        else:
            simlnkname = os.path.abspath(outputdir+"/"+pos)
            if os.path.exists(simlnkname):
                simlnkname += suffix
            os.symlink(name, simlnkname)


def chechdir(directory):
    if not (os.path.exists(directory) and os.path.isdir(directory)):
        print "Error directory ", directory
        return False
    return True

if __name__ == "__main__":
    inp = "dir1"
    outp = "dir2"
    maker(inp, outp)
```

Test it:

```
$ tree
.
├── dir1
│   ├── bash
│   ├── exe1
│   ├── paper
│   │   ├── bash
│   │   ├── file1
│   │   ├── file2
│   │   └── file3
│   └── sh1
├── dir2
└── test.py

3 directories, 8 files
$ python test.py 
$ tree
.
├── dir1
│   ├── bash
│   ├── exe1
│   ├── paper
│   │   ├── bash
│   │   ├── file1
│   │   ├── file2
│   │   └── file3
│   └── sh1
├── dir2
│   ├── bash -> /home/miha/exampldir/dir1/bash
│   ├── bash1 -> /home/miha/exampldir/dir1/paper/bash
│   ├── exe1 -> /home/miha/exampldir/dir1/exe1
│   ├── file1 -> /home/miha/exampldir/dir1/paper/file1
│   ├── file2 -> /home/miha/exampldir/dir1/paper/file2
│   ├── file3 -> /home/miha/exampldir/dir1/paper/file3
│   └── sh1 -> /home/miha/exampldir/dir1/sh1
└── test.py

3 directories, 15 files
```

It concept, what work in linux. So it's reason to clean `outp` (`dir2` other words) before run it.